# How can I run GHCi against a compiled package?

Tags: haskell, package, cabal, ghci

I should really know this by now, but I don't. I'm often working on a Cabal-based package and have just run a successful `cabal build`. Now I want to try some things out in GHCi. If I run `cabal repl`, then GHC recompiles the whole package into bytecode and runs it in the interpreter. Not what I want at all! If I were just running GHCi directly, I'd use something like `-O -fobject-code`, but that won't give me the package context. I just want "Give me a repl with the package as it's been compiled, compiling additional things only as necessary." How do I do it?

Comment: I'm using `stack repl --package foo` for this.

Comment: @arrowd, we're not using `stack` for this project. Are you suggesting some way to point `stack` at a local Cabal project? I know even less about it than I know about Cabal.

Comment: Nope, I just saying that it works with Stack fine. Dunno what to do if you're using plain Cabal.

Comment: @arrowd That doesn't seem to work for me. `stack repl` alone interprets the current package (named `test` in my test, original, I know), while `stack repl --package test` reports "The package test was specified in multiple, incompatible ways: test test" (and exits without dropping me into ghci). To reproduce, these are the initialization commands I used: `mkdir test; cd test; cabal init --lib --non-interactive; stack init`. (Perhaps I am using `stack` incorrectly?)

Comment: No, I did understand you incorrectly. I thought that under "compiled" package you meant some dependency package of your project. So, you basically want to feed Cabal's `new-dist` dir to GHCi so that it wouldn't recompile it, right?

Comment: @arrowd Right, feed cabal's `dist-newstyle` to ghci. I don't know dfeuer's needs for sure, but besides recompiling, using the object code often makes a serious performance difference, and I wouldn't be surprised if that's part of the motivation for this question.

Comment: Hope this inspires some ideas. Some years ago (not that many), the scala compiler was really bad at detecting what needed to be recompiled, adding to that it was a slow compiler back then. I found a away around it by creating a new project in a fresh independent folder and would symlinke one of the project folders to the folder containing the source I'd like to mess with. This worked in JVM because the search path for classes files respects the order of the paths and all the linking is dynamic.

Comment: @DanielWagner, my primary goal at the moment is recompilation avoidance, but yes, getting the optimization right is often very useful, and could be particularly important for some things in this project.

Comment: @pedrofurla, I wonder if I could do something like running `cabal repl` in a different *package* within the same *project*, where said package just re-exports modules from the first one. It sounds like a horrible hack, but ... maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the right way, but I do know a workaround that can sometimes be useful. If the thing you care about is a library component, you can ask for a repl for an executable component.

Comment: Can you possibly give a worked example?

Comment: BTW: I don't want to render my question "too broad", but it would also be very useful to know how to compile an arbitrary Haskell module against a package that I've just built, to see how it optimizes. As you probably know, I tend to look at a lot of Core.

Comment: @dfeuer What... would a worked example look like?

Comment: What exactly does it mean to ask for a repl for an executable component?

Comment: @dfeuer `cabal repl exe:this-executable-only-exists-to-get-a-repl-with-the-library-compiled`. Or you can ask for an executable that the package already offers if it has one and you're faint-hearted. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe `--repl-options -fobject-code` kind of does what you want:

```
cabal repl --repl-options -fobject-code --repl-options -O --builddir dist-repl
```

This will give you incremental building of compiled code as you work in GHCi. Caveats:

- `dist-repl` is an alternative directory for the `-fobject-code` build objects. As  of *cabal* 3.6.2.0 at least, trying to reuse the regular output from `cabal build` leads to some unnecessary rebuilds and other strange behaviour, as reported at [*cabal* issue #3565](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/3565). That being so, it's better to compromise and use `--builddir` to keep a separate set of build objects. Note that `cabal clean` accepts the `--builddir` option just fine.
- Setting the optimisation level explicitly is necessary, as otherwise the default `-O0` from `cabal repl` will override your package setting.

Comment: That sounds very messy indeed.

Comment: @dfeuer I found some discussion of that issue at [*cabal* issue #3565](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/3565). A workaround/compromise suggested there is using `--builddir` to keep a separate set of object files for `cabal repl` at a different directory.